# Material-UI: How to immediately click on another select field after one is already focused

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

After selecting a field, how can I immediately click on a different field to have it focused without having to click it twice? Is there a prop in Material-UI that can disable this behavior?

Here's a link to the sample code

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-cekgv?file=/demo.js

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand your question. Can you better explain it?

Comment: If the "Tag" field is focused, I can see its options. While the field is focused, I want to click on the "Chip" field and see its labels. However, clicking on the chip field only closes the tag field. I'm gonna have to click it again to have the chip field focused.

Comment: I think this is the default behavior of multiple select in Material UI. The only thing that I think will work is to make the second click dynamic. So when you are handling the closing event of select, then maybe you can trigger the same click on the same place.

Comment: But I would suggest you don't worry about that double click, because it is no big deal.

Comment: Well, I think it would be inconvenient for the users to double click every time they want to focus on something else. If they want to click on a button while the field is focused, then they have to double click it.